# TabBarItem icon does not appear immediately in ios 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, ios8

I have a problem with tabBarItem icon.Here is a screenshot of a part of my storyboard.

[image: Storyboard]

There is a basic viewController with some buttons. When one of these buttons is touched up, a tabBarController with three tabs appears.**In iOS 8**,icons of tabBarItems does not appear initially.If i change view controller,both icons of previous and current view controller appear.if i select the third tab,then all icons of tabBarItems appear.Here is a screenshot of my problem:

First Appearance of TabBarController :

[image: 1st]

If i change tab:

[image: 2nd]

Here is the code that i use to set icons(all icons are 30x30) of tabBarItems into viewDidLoad method of first viewController of TabBarController:

```
[[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] tabBarItem]  setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1d1.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1b1.png"]];

[[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] tabBarItem]  setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2d1.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2b1.png"]];

[[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] tabBarItem]  setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3d1.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3b1.png"]];
```

Here is a screenshot of iOS 7 that it works properly:

[image: right]

Can anyone help me with this??

Comment: Did you try it on a device too?

Comment: @HAS i did not try on a device yet cause i haven't a device with iOS 8 at the moment. Do you think that simulator may cause this issue?? But why does this happen only on simulator of iOS 8?

Comment: All the simulators are all the time full of bugs (okay, that's greatly exaggerated of course, but you should never trust it when an issue occurs.)

Comment: @HAS Hehe you have right. I will run my app on iOS 8 device next days and i will inform you if the simulator causes the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some hours of searching and reading different answers including @Zala's answer,this part of code into viewDidLoad of first viewController of TabBarController made the difference and finally worked.

```
 if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
{

    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

    UIImage *unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1b1.png"];
    UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1d1.png"];

    [tabBarItem setImage: [unselectedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [tabBarItem setSelectedImage:[selectedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];


    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];

    UIImage *unselectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2b1.png"];
    UIImage *selectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2d1.png"];

    [tabBarItem1 setImage: [unselectedImage1 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [tabBarItem1 setSelectedImage: [selectedImage1 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];

    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];

    UIImage *unselectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3b1.png"];
    UIImage *selectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3d1.png"];

    [tabBarItem2 setImage: [unselectedImage2 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [tabBarItem2 setSelectedImage:[selectedImage2 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];


    [tabBarItem setTitle:@"Φωτογραφίες"];

    [tabBarItem2 setTitle:@"360° Φωτογραφία"];

    [tabBarItem1 setTitle:@"Βίντεο"];



}
else
{


    [[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] tabBarItem]  setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1d1.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1b1.png"]];


    [[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] tabBarItem]  setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2d1.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2b1.png"]];
    [[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] tabBarItem]  setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3d1.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3b1.png"]];

    [[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] tabBarItem] setTitle:@"Φωτογραφίες"];

    [[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] tabBarItem] setTitle:@"360° Φωτογραφία"];

    [[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] tabBarItem] setTitle:@"Βίντεο"];



}
```

Answer (score 5):

`setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage:` is deprecated from iOS 7 use `image` and `selectedImage` property of `UITabBarItem` instead.

To set the custom image:

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

if ([self iOS7OrAbove])
{
    //use UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal to set the custom image for ios 7 and above.
    tabBarItem1.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"SelectedImage"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    tabBarItem1.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"UnselectedImage"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
}
else
{
    [tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SelectedImage"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UnselectedImage"]];
}
```

Hope this works fine.

Even if `setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage:` is deprecated in iOS7, it is working fine in iOS7 but not in 8.

Comment: Neither this works mate. I tried to import this part of code in TabBarController or viewDidLoad method of first ViewController and no icon appears in both cases at anytime.

Comment: Can you check by setting the tabbar in viewWillAppear, Because I had the same problem.

Comment: Are you using the login screen(withOut tabbar) and then segueing to the other screen? If it is the case then you should set the tabbar in viewWillAppear of the first screen that displays the tabbar.

Comment: Please check screenshot of my storyboard to understand the structure of UI.

Comment: You can check by adding the code(set tabbar items) in fist controller (in viewWillAppear) that is present after UITabBarController.

Comment: @hoya21 Are you adding the code to all three controllers(first controllers after tabbarcontroller), for this to work?

Comment: No @zala, only into first controller of tabBarController. Furthermore into viewDidLoad method of first tab ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

You can set these images via storyboard too:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z8iL.jpg

If you want this in a dynamic way, I would suggest to inherit from UITabBarController and overwrite it's viewWillAppear:

Comment: I tried from storyboard too. Also i tried to fix it from TabBarController but i didn't make sense.

Comment: You are right, that doesn't make no sense ;)

By the way: [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] called from the first vc is equal to self

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this cannot be done using storyboards - needs code to be written.

You have to code it in viewdidload action

```
UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBar;

UITabBarItem *targetTabBarItem = [[tabbar items] objectAtIndex:0]; // whichever tab-item
UIImage *selectedIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"name-of-selected-image.png"];
[targetTabBarItem setSelectedImage:selectedIcon];
```